# Passing angular element to bootstrap table formatter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-table

I am attempting to add an angular element to a bootstrap table using a bootstrap table formatter. The bootstrap table loads into the formatter ok as data is loaded in, which creates the element and binds the click event to it.

Formatter:

```
job.enterAddressFormatter = function (value, row) {
     var button = angular.element("useAddress");
     button.addClass("btn-icon");
     button.bind("click", job.addressToForm(row));
     var icon = document.createElement("i");
     icon.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-paste");
     return button;
}
```

This runs with no errors and instead of returning an element (div, button, whatever) it loads the element as the console would as `[object Object]`.

I've tried using the formatter to return a string that the browser can then read as a standard HTML5 button, but then I lose the click event. So I sort of feel like I'm in a lose-lose situation at the moment. I can see the problem is with the elements being generated after the angular compile - but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: what does `console.log(button)` look like? You're returning an object while your bootstrap table is probably expecting a dom element. I haven't used bootstrap table before

Comment: Console log shows pretty much the same thing as the table (`[object Object]`) - the table can take any html basically so can be text, buttons, icons images etc. but this isn't rendering as a html element - its showing as plain text like the console